# "Canonical" questions & answers on Project Management

Tags: discussion, faq, answers, canonical

Project Management SE joins its [siblings](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years) in maintaining a list of ["canonical" questions & answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). Please place candidate questions into answers (except Q&As that have been discussed in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and created as "canonicals" from the outset). The full list is in the accepted answer.

Comment: I went ahead and made the answer community wiki so everyone can edit it, which will help keep it cleaner and easier to find information that belongs to a specific category. I see where you're going with this, and I think it's a good idea. It may also help with our discussions on tags.

Comment: I would suggest we put more thought into the concept of canonical questions. The answers given are generally meant to solve a very specific problem for the OP. It is a stretch to say that what works for one person works for everyone or that it represents a comprehensive or complete answer to a question.  PM questions do not have single solutions. Where there are recommended best practices to address a challenge, it may not be reflected in an answer on PMSE. The answers are focused on helping the OP rather than being 'canonical.'

Comment: @MarkPhillips : agree with you. Without much feedback thus far was using (and abusing) own list of favorites to produce candidate Q/As (as you might have noticed, I haven't yet accepted my own answer which means strictly speaking there are no canonicals **yet**). As for "no size fits all" - you are right, however this is not an obstacle in itself. Those who are into PM or management in general usually understand full well the futility of fixed recipes and will take the label "canonical" with a grain of salt anyway.

Comment: @DeerHunter  If it needs to be taken with a grain of salt, I would say we should reconsider. Standards are used most by people who don't feel comfortable "tailoring" their processes i.e. taking it with a grain of salt. We should be careful trying to be a canonical source on a topic.

Comment: @MarkPhillips - no problem, question title and content edited a tiny bit to emphasize your point. Please feel free to edit further. We cannot guard against doctrinaire fools, though, fools are very ingenious...

Comment: @DeerHunter - Where do you think this question goes?  http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/project-manager-profession-or-role

Comment: @jmort253 - Added the question to the top, added a new section with a slightly verbose title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Definitions in the discipline of Project Management**

- [Project Manager, profession or role?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/project-manager-profession-or-role)
- [What are the definitions and distinctions between Project x Program x Portfolio x Product Managers?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9123/what-are-the-definitions-and-distinctions-between-these-roles)

**Team management and leadership**

- [As a PM, How do you select your project team members?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/631/as-a-pm-how-do-you-select-your-project-team-members)
- [How to Avoid Micro-Managing a Software Development Team?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-to-avoid-micro-managing-a-software-development-team)
- [Which skill set is necessary for a project manager?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/77/which-skill-set-is-necessary-for-a-project-manager)
- [How to get burned out team back engaged again?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-to-get-burned-out-team-back-engaged-again)
- [What are the biggest mistakes that new project managers make?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/92/what-are-the-biggest-mistakes-that-new-project-managers-make)

**Planning and budgeting**

- [How to estimate amount of work/man hours for an unfamiliar task?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25/how-to-estimate-amount-of-work-man-hours-for-an-unfamiliar-task)
- [How to calculate budget margin?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/943/how-to-calculate-budget-margin)
- [Is WIFO a good project management method?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/is-wifo-a-good-project-management-method)

**Working in a global environment**

- [Managing projects across time zones](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/982/managing-projects-across-time-zones)

**Projects and organizations**

**Scope management**

- [How can I complete a project with unfixed requirements from the client?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8864/how-can-i-complete-a-project-with-unfixed-requirements-from-the-client)

**Change management**

**Risk management**

- [How do you manage technical debt?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/how-do-you-manage-technical-debt)
- [What went wrong - project going off track](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/what-went-wrong-project-going-off-track)

**Communication management**

- [Number of people in a team that need to communicate with the client?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/number-of-people-in-a-team-that-need-to-communicate-with-the-client)
- [Should I explain the root cause of a bug when a client asks for it?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/should-i-explain-the-root-cause-of-a-bug-when-a-client-asks-for-it)

**Software development methodologies**

- [When to Use Waterfall, When to Use Scrum ?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/389/when-to-use-waterfall-when-to-use-scrum)
- [Integrating Critical Chain into Scrum/Agile Practices](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/343/integrating-critical-chain-into-scrum-agile-practices)
- [What is the role of a QA tester on a Scrum team?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/what-is-the-role-of-a-qa-tester-on-a-scrum-team)
- [Different ways of running Retrospectives](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/different-ways-of-running-retrospectives)

**Useful tools, hardware and software**

- [How do I select project management software for our current workflow?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/how-do-i-select-project-management-software-for-our-current-workflow)

Comment: The Q on scope management is a bit iffy.